# "Cannot open cource file" in a number of 400+ / Visual Studio Enterprise 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enterprise

When I try to compile any project in C++ I get a lot of errors about missing source files (errno.h, float.h, correct.g, etc.). I tried reinstalling (along with removing the Visual Studio Installer), checked if the Visual Studio SDK and Windows SDK are installed - according to the Visual Studio Installer they are. I have never encountered such a problem before. The only thing I can consider to be the reason is that I had installed Visual Studio on the Disk G, and then I changed it's letter for D. I reinstalled my system (Windows 10), after which my computer did not detect my second disk, so I added it manually, installed Visual (when disc was G) and after that I changed it to the D (Visual is installed on the other disk, but download cache and tool like sdk are installed on this G/D disk). I also changed the registers of Visual so they did not have values for non-existent disk. Do you have any ideas how to repair it without reinstalling the system?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the SDKs themselves?

Comment: You mean uncheck in Visual Studio installer Visual Studio SDK and Windows SDK and later install them the same way?

Comment: No, I thought these were installed separately.

Comment: Unsure though. Windows installers are tricky. And there *must* be a reference to G: somewhere, either in the registry or in VS or SDK files. You can try searching specifically for `G:`.

Comment: @numzero You are right, there are a lot of  "G:" in registry, so now I've got another question. Do you know if there is and option to find out all of them and change automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so I was able to change all registry data, but it didn;t helped at all.

Comment: EDIT: I've solved the problem. First of all - changed all the registry. Next - I do not know why and how, but Visual Studio Installer got Windows SDK in the newest version only for 1 component, when the rest of components get only older version of SDK. As you can guess I've got installed the lastest version and compiler has not seen proper files (actually there were no such files at all). So I had to install older version of SKD in all possible components.